# What is the equivalent to npm install --legacy-peer-deps for pnpm?

Tags: pnpm

What is the equivalent of `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` for [pnpm](https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm#:%7E:text=pnpm%20uses%20a%20content%2Daddressable%20filesystem%20to%20store%20all%20files%20from%20all%20module%20directories%20on%20a%20disk)?

I tried `pnpm install --legacy-peer-deps` but it is not recognized:

```
 ERROR   ERROR  Unknown option: 'legacy-peer-deps'
Did you mean 'strict-peer-dependencies'? Use "--config.unknown=value" to force an unknown option.
```

Should I just use `pnpm config set auto-install-peers true` and then `pnpm install`?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do - why use legacy behaviour from another package manager in a new one?

Comment: I am trying to build a project and it is failing with `pnpm install`, but succeeds with `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`.

Comment: Failing _how_, specifically? Maybe that's the thing to give a [mre] of, it's possibly an XY problem.